# The pipe 'async' could not be found in Angular + Spartacus

Tags: angular, spartacus-storefront

As above, when I try to use *async* keyword I am getting in the browser error. I am importing CommonModule in my custom module. Can't find the reason why it's not working.

Error:

```
ERROR Error: The pipe 'async' could not be found!
    Angular 2
        getPipeDef$1
        pipe
```

```
Node: 12.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 10.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
... service-worker
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1002.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1002.3
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.3
@angular/cli                    10.2.3
@schematics/angular             10.2.3
@schematics/update              0.1002.3
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.7
```

Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class IngenicoPaymentMethodModule { }
```

My component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActiveCartService, UserIdService } from '@spartacus/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PaymentMethodService, PaymentProduct } from './facade/payment-method.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ingenico-payment-method',
  templateUrl: './ingenico-payment-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ingenico-payment-method.component.scss']
})
export class IngenicoPaymentMethodComponent implements OnInit {
  paymentMethods$: Observable<PaymentProduct[]>;

  constructor(
    protected paymentMethodService: PaymentMethodService,
    protected activeCartService: ActiveCartService,
    protected userIdService: UserIdService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let userId, cartId;

    this.userIdService.getUserId()
      .subscribe(occId => userId = occId)
      .unsubscribe();


    this.activeCartService.getActiveCartId().subscribe(occId => cartId = occId).unsubscribe();

    if (userId && cartId) {
      this.paymentMethods$ = this.paymentMethodService.getPaymentMethods(userId, cartId);
    }


  }

}
```

Template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="paymentMethods$ | async as paymentMethods"></ng-container>
```

As you can see above I am importing CommonModule, yet it's not visible by the browser.

Comment: In what module you defined `IngenicoPaymentMethodComponent` component?

Answer (score 3):

Please **declare** your component in the same module where you import the `CommonModule`. Only then the `async` pipe will be accessible in the component's template:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [IngenicoPaymentMethodComponent] // <----------------
})
export class IngenicoPaymentMethodModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can opt out of Ivy usage by setting:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

in your `tsconfig.app.json` and this should fix your issue.

Comment: Can you help me understand how opting out from IVY can help solve this problem? At the first sight, it seem unrelated to me...